# Bash odd numbers

Tags: script

I wrote this bash script to print odd numbers, but the code is not working there is something wrong with the if statement. Could someone point out the mistake?

```
for((c=0;c<100;c++));
do
if ["$c" % 2 != 0] ; then 
echo $c;
fi
done;
```

Answer (score 2):

This sounds a little like a school assignment so here are the bits of information you need to get the job done, rather than the final answer.

First of all `[` is a command line utility. So the error you're probably getting `bash: [0: command not found` etc. is trying to tell you that bash needs a space to understand the arguments you are passing.

The next issue is `[` is looking for a statement that evaluates to a boolean. You probably want to find a way to sub shell or otherwise encapsulate the math. Look into `expr`

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you. I got it right,

for((c=1;c<100;c++));
do
let "out=$c%2"
if [ "$out" != "0" ]; then 
echo $c;
fi;
done;

Answer (score 1):

for people that might be looking for this information
this task can be done with:

> seq 1 2 99

to understand it better you might want to check:

> man seq